# Finding (and highlighting) URL text fragments in a web page

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

I'd like to use JavaScript to implement the [WIGC spec](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment) for text selection from URL fragments on a webpage.

From the linked document:

> Allow specifying text as part of the URL fragment:
>
> [https://example.com#:~:text=prefix-,startText,endText,-suffix](https://example.com#:%7E:text=prefix-,startText,endText,-suffix)
>
> Using this syntax
>
> ```
> :~:text=[prefix-,]textStart[,textEnd][,-suffix]
>
>          context  |-------match-----|  context
> ```
>
> *(Square brackets indicate an optional parameter)*
>
> Navigating to such a URL will cause the browser to indicate the first instance of the matched text.

This is currently implemented in Chrome, but I would like to make it work in other browsers too if someone lands on one of my pages with such a fragment.

Here's an example link that doesn't use prefix or suffix:

[https://example.com/#:~:text=This%20domain%20is%20for%20use%20in%20illustrative%20examples%20in%20documents](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=This%20domain%20is%20for%20use%20in%20illustrative%20examples%20in%20documents)

And one that uses both:

[https://example.com/#:~:text=You%20may%20use-,this,-domain%20in%20literature](https://example.com/#:%7E:text=You%20may%20use-,this,-domain%20in%20literature)

(you can see the highlights if you open these links with a recent version of Chrome).

I'd like to be able to fallback nicely if e.g. I can't find the `textStart` or `textEnd` but can find the `prefix` or `suffix`

I know that I can use [Ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) to select and highlight text on the page, and I assume this is the best approach.  It seems that Ranges require a node and a text- or child-based offset, so the question becomes how to find the relevant node and offset.

I have played around with `window.find`, but I'm not sure how to turn that into a node/offset pair, plus it has additional behaviour in some browsers that I don't really want (lack of control over the highlights, scrolling around, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There is [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/text-fragments-polyfill) that implements exactly the same. Probably you could just use it?